# Plotly in jupyter: only the last 8 figures shown when using for-loop

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, plotly, jupyter

I have a jupyter-notebook, where I plot several plotly scatter figures via a for-loop:

```
for i in myColumnList:
    for j in myColumnList
        fig = px.scatter(df, x=i, y=j)
        fig.show()
```

As soon as more than 8 figures are shown, the older ones start to vanish.
How can I fix this?

```
plotly==5.16.0
jupyter==1.0.0
jupyter-client==6.1.12
jupyter-console==6.4.2
jupyter-contrib-core==0.4.2
jupyter-server==1.24.0
jupyter_core==5.3.1
jupyterlab_server==2.24.0
```

Comment: What you report is not reproducible with what little information you have provided thus far. I have posted an 'answer' to share code that disagrees with your statement. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), especially the section 'Help others reproduce the problem' where it talks about creating a minimal reproducible example. Minor thing. I missing what versions you are using from the second code block you share. I see JupyterLab listed and no Notebook, but you text and tags only reference Jupyter Notebook.

Answer (score 1):

In order to share code I need to post as an 'answer'.
What you report is not reproducible with what little information you have provided thus far.
I am seeing 23 Plotly plots display just fine with the following code running in a temporary Jupyter session [launched via here](https://mybinder.org/v2/gh/fomightez/3Dscatter_plot-binder/master?filepath=index.ipynb) in both JupyterLab Version 3.4.8 and Jupyter Notebook (NbClassic 0.4.8):

```py
import plotly.express as px
df = px.data.iris()
fig = px.scatter(df, x='sepal_length', y='sepal_width',
              color='species')
fig.show()
for i in range(22):
    fig = px.scatter(x=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4], y=[0, 1, 4, 9, 16], title = i+1)
    fig.show()
```

I also further confirmed in both JupyterLab Version 4.1.2 and Jupyter Notebook 7.1.0 my toy code above displays 23 Plotly plots fine, too.

Answer (score -1):

you can use [subplots](https://plotly.com/python/subplots/) to plot them all in one figure (you can stack them vertically). just change the row number in the loop.